# Detecting a word in paragraph image on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract on iOS to extract a word from an image.
The Image contains a single word only.

Now I'm trying to detect a word from a paragraph  by simply tapping a word in the image and this word will get highlighted and extracted by tesseract.

**The Question is:**
How can i detect, highlight and extract the word from a paragraph when the user taps on it?

Comment: what you have did ? i need to correct.... show your code shot and simple

Comment: @Spynet actually i can't figure out how to solve this issue. the only thing i did is to detect a single word from an image. note: the image has nothing but this word.